# Including all dependencies in Static Library

Tags: c, static-libraries, codeblocks, static-linking, extern

I often get *unresolved symbol* errors when linking my static C libraries with binaries compiled in other languages. For some simple libraries it works without problem. But for others I get these types of errors:

```
...unresolved external symbol '__chkstk_ms'
...unresolved external symbol '_stat'
```

***(anyone know which libraries these symbols are from?)***

I use Code::Blocks by the way, and usually only one procedure will be declared with the ***extern*** directive.

Is there any method or setting to ensure that all dependencies are included in the static library? Could this be causing the *unresolved external symbol* errors?

TIA.

Comment: You have a static C library where you use a C++ library?  Should this be tagged with C++ (and perhaps not with C)?

Comment: Hello dave. Pardon, but I'm not an expert on the subject. What do you mean? The program that is attempting to link to the static library is able to link to other C static libraries without issue. Do you mean that this particular static library has been compiled as a C++ library?

Comment: Code::Blocks is a C++ IDE, so I'm not sure if it is doing something weird like trying to call the C++ linker or something.

Comment: Wasn't aware! Thought that it'll compile C as well.